# How to add a String to an ArrayList from inside "onDataChange" Listener?

Tags: android

I am not able to add a String to my ArrayList from inside the for-Loop (outside it works fine)
I dont get an exception error.

I have already checked that the for-Loop is active at least one time (3 times).

```
ArrayList<String> list;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("xyz");           // <--- this is getting added

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                try {
                     list.add("x");  // <--- this isn't getting added.                              
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(test.this, "error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(test.this, "error: " + databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I just wanted to add a String from inside the for-Loop, but it wont work.

Comment: Hi Joel, are you sure you have children in `databaseReference`? Will you please mention your firebase database structure in question? or check if you actually have children in the `databaseReference` node?

Comment: @Omkar before i added a Toast Inside the for Loop. The Toast was shown 3 Times, because the Database Reference hast 3 Children

Comment: @MarkKeen list is instance variable. It is not require to be final.

Comment: @Omkar that wasn't apparent before the edit

Comment: Are you trying to access the Arraylist synchronously?

Comment: @MarkKeen I did not synchronize the ArrayList (you see it in the Code), I think it wont make a difference, because from outside the ValueEventListener Method, i can add as many Strings as i want

Comment: When I use the ArrayAdapter, the data from the ArrayList is shown in the ListView, it is very confusing

Comment: That is because you tried to access the data before the callback method `onDataChange`  in `ValueEventListener` was called (this is called at some point in the future when the data is available), so really this is just a timing issue

Comment: @MarkKeen so you dont have a solution for my problem ? I have seen YouTube Videos where the RecyclerView is used, but that is way more complicated.

Comment: I have discovered something interesting: When i add a Toast inside the for-Loop, and a Toast outside (after the ValueEventListener), the Toast from outside is displayed first, then 3 times the Toast from inside the for-Loop. How can this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have solved the Problem**

Because of the fact, that the ValueEventListener is running asynchronously, which means, that, when the compiler runs your code, the ValueEventListener runs in another thread, and the rest of the code runs at the same time, I wasnt able, to add the String into the ArrayList.

To get the requested Data from the Firebase Database, it will take a few seconds, and in that time, the Code was already finished with compiling. That is the Reason, why the Toast Message said, that the ArrayList was empty, even though the Strings were actually added to the List, but too late.

This is what Ive done:
I added this inside the onDataChange method:

```
OnComplete();
```

Then, outside the onCreate method, I created the OnComplete method:

```
    private void OnComplete() {


    array = list.toArray();
    String arraySize = Integer.toString(list.size());
    Toast.makeText(test.this, "ArraySize: " + arraySize, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

This solution has solved my Problem.

Thank you (Omkar & Mark) for taking your Time to help me!!